# How to update database of ~25,000 music files?

Tags: mysql, database, file

### Update:

I wrote a working script that finishes this job in a reasonable length of time, and seems to be quite reliable. It's coded entirely in PHP and is built around the array_diff() idea suggested by saccharine (so, thanks saccharine!).

### You can access the source code here: http://pastebin.com/ddeiiEET

I have a MySQL database that is an index of mp3 files in a certain directory, together with their attributes (ie. title/artist/album).

New files are often being added to the music directory. At the moment it contains about 25,000 MP3 files, but I need to create a cron job that goes through it each day or so, adding any files that it doesn't find in the database.

The problem is that I don't know what is the best / least taxing way of doing this. I'm assuming a MySQL query would have to be run for *each* file on *each* cron run (to check if it's already indexed), so the script would unavoidably take a little while to run (which is okay; it's an automated process). However, because of this, my usual language of choice (PHP) would probably not suffice, as it is not designed to run long-running scripts like this (or is it...?).

It would obviously be nice, but I'm not fussed about deleting index entries for deleted files (if files actually get deleted, it's always manual cleaning up, and I don't mind just going into the database by hand to fix the index).

By the way, it would be recursive; the files are mostly situated in an Artist/Album/Title.mp3 structure, however they aren't religiously ordered like this and the script would certainly have to be able to fetch ID3 tags for new files. In fact, ideally, I would like the script to fetch ID3 tags for *each* file on every run, and either add a new row to the database or update the existing one if it had changed.

Anyway, I'm starting from the ground up with this, so the most basic advice first I guess (such as which programming language to use - I'm willing to learn a new one if necessary). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a dumb question, would it not be possible to simply order the files by date added and only run the iterations through the files added in the last day? I'm not very familiar working with files, but it seems like it should be possible.

If all you want to do is improve the speed of your current code, I would recommend that you check that your data is properly indexed. It makes queries a lot faster if you search through a table's index. If you're searching through columns that aren't the key, you might want to change your setup. You should also avoid using "SELECT *" and instead use "SELECT COUNT" as mysql will then be returning ints instead of objects.

You can also do everything in a few mysql queries but will increase the complexity of your php code. Call the array with information about all the files $files. Select the data from the db where the files in the db match the a file in $files. Something like this.

```
"SELECT id FROM MUSIC WHERE id IN ($files)"
```

Read the returned array and label it $db_files. Then find all files in $files array that don't appear in $db_files array using array_diff(). Label the missing files $missing_files. Then insert the files in $missing_files into the db.

Comment: I don't have any code atm ;-) And that is an interesting idea. The current entries all have date_modified data, so I could actually just get the most recent file in the database and add all files that are above this. Or, like you said I could go with the array_diff() solution. I'll do some tests. Thanks!

Comment: @FelaMaslen No problem. Let me know of your results if you do any speed tests. I'm sort of interested in whether this kind of relational algebra should be done in database or script.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the business of fetching the list of filenames that need adding to the database is pretty quick (less than ten seconds on my server). I'm now stuck on the best way to fetch the ID3 tags (I could implement it using getid3() for PHP, but it would take minutes to process a couple of thousand files at the rate I measured for one file).

Comment: An update: I went with a cron PHP script solution (PHP-CLI). It calculates every single file in the directory, and adds any that aren't in the database (using getid3 1.9 to fetch the tags), as well as removes stuff from the database that doesn't exist anymore. It takes max. a couple of minutes to run, which is fine for a cron job at 6:00 AM (also, the MySQL query part of it generally takes (much) less than a second).

Comment: @FelaMaslen So I take it you went with the array_diff solution? Or did you do it some other way? Also congrats on getting a reasonable solution to work.

Comment: Yeah, I went with array_diff, seems to work okay. Love it when something runs as a cron job, and you forget ever having to do XYZ manually :) BTW, I could post a link to the source code if you want?

Comment: @FelaMaslen I don't particularly need it, but it'll probably be useful to whoever else stumbles on this question with the same problem. I was going to warn you but one of the older versions of php had a really slow array_diff() function that made it better to simply write your own using a loop. Glad yours worked though without the hassle.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3 on my server so it works okay. I'll add the source code to a pastebin and link it to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Engine are you using? If you're using MyISAM, the whole table will be locked while updating your table. But still, 25k rows are not that much, so basically in (max) a few minutes it should be updated. If it is InnoDB just update it since it's row-level locked and you should be still able to use your table while updating it.

By the way, if you're not using any fulltext search on that table, I believe that you should convert it to InnoDB as you can use foreign indexes, and that would help you a lot while joining tables. Also, it scales better AFAIK.

Comment: Here's the thing: I'm using MyISAM and full-text search (although wouldn't mind sacrificing that ability). BUT: the script, as I see it, would be executing many small queries, rather than one large one. Ie. one query for each file, and one more query for each new file.